# How to run function after D3 TOPOJSON map loads

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I am trying to run a function that shades the individual states of a TOPOJSON D3 map based on data.

However, the function keeps running before the states load/appear in the SVG. The function that builds the map is called in a document ready function. I've tried adding an event listener to the states, an .on attribute that calls the function that is supposed to shade the states and have used window.load. But the function that shades the states keeps running before the states appear on screen and thus returns a NULL value when trying to find each state by their id

```
.background {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

#states {
  fill: #aaa;
}

#states .active {
  fill: orange;
}

#state-borders {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function buildmap(){
var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    centered;

var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
    .scale(1070)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", clicked);

var g = svg.append("g");

d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
  if (error) throw error;

  g.append("g")
      .attr("id", "states")
    .selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);

  g.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
      .attr("id", "state-borders")
      .attr("d", path);
});
};

function colorstates(){
   var mainstate = document.getElementById("texas")
   mainstate.style.fill="blue"
}



 $(document).ready(function((){
      buildmap()
      colorstates() //I have also used window.load and adding .on attribute to svg/d3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d3.json` is asynchronous. It means that all the code that comes after it will run *immediately*, that is, the code *will not wait* for `d3.json` to finish.

Using `$(document).ready()` or `window.load` won't make any difference. The paths will appear in the DOM only after `d3.json` gets the file (btw, a big file) and paints the SVG. Thus, you'll have to wait for `d3.json` to finish, so you can select those paths.

**Solution**: call your function at the bottom of `d3.json`:

```
d3.json("/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json", function(error, us) {
    if (error) throw error;

    g.append("g")
        .attr("id", "states")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", path);

    g.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
            return a !== b;
        }))
        .attr("id", "state-borders")
        .attr("d", path);

    //calling colorstates inside d3.json
    colorstates() 

    function colorstates() {
        var mainstate = document.getElementById("texas")
        mainstate.style.fill = "blue"
    }

});
```

That way, the elements will be there when you call your `colorstates` function.

**EDIT**: To select the state (that is, the path) by ID, you'll have to set the paths' IDs first (right now, they have no ID):

```
g.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) {
        return a !== b;
    }))
    .attr("id", d => "state" + d.id)
    .attr("d", path);
```

In the `topoJSON`, the `d.id`s are numbers, and you cannot start an ID by a number (that's why I used `"state" + d.id`). Texas' id is 48.

Here is your code, working: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/b2114787193d018fc094763a92872333

PS: you don't need to use `document.getElementById` in a D3 code. You'll see that using D3 selectors is easier and more versatile.

PS2: Your state borders should have "state-borders" as a `class`, not as an `id`: you **cannot** have the same ID for different elements. IDs are unique.

Comment: This still returns mainstate as null. I moved the colorstates() call to d3.json before and after defining the function. Both return mainstate as null.

Comment: So, you have *another* problem: no element with ID = "texas". How are you setting the IDs?

Comment: "texas" is created when the features are created in d3 from the topojson. I added an alert to colorstates() and the alert runs before the map appears in the browser.

Comment: But there is no DOM element with that ID.

Comment: Isn't the DOM element is the "g" svg? Despite that, it seems colorstates() is still running before the map appears because the alert is appearing before the map.

Comment: There is no element, be it a g, a path, or whatever, with that ID. Check the edit, where I show you how you can do it. What you said (*""texas" is created when the features are created in d3 from the topojson"*) is not correct, because D3 only creates three things in the DOM: an SVG, a group inside the SVG and several paths inside the group. And none of them have the ID "texas".

Comment: Oh, okay, I see. I added `.attr("id", d => "state" + d.id)` and it worked. Thank you.